# How to match default UITableViewCell X-position/leading constraint in static UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a static UITable view with 4 cells: the first and last cells are custom, while the second and third cells use a built-in style ("Basic" and "Right Detail", respectively). I have the following constraints on the label in the first and last cells:

- label.leading = superview.leading + 20
- label.Center Y = superview.Center Y

I'm having trouble matching the constraints for my custom UITableViewCell labels to those of the default UITableViewCells (the ones using the built-in styles).

For certain devices (e.g iPhone XR) the X position of the labels match for all four cells (20):

[image: iPhone XR]

But for other devices (e.g. iPhone Xs) the X position of the labels do not match (16 vs 20):

[image: iPhone Xs]

Note the X position of the first and last cell is greater (20) than that of the second and third cell (16).

At first I thought that the constraints for the default cells were being varied based on the size classes of the device, but both the iPhone XR and Xs have compact width (wC) and regular height (hR).

Any idea how I can match my custom cell's label constraints to those of the default UITableView cell's label?

Answer (score 0):

`textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` are present even in a subclassed `UITableViewCell`. While using `textLabel` instead of a custom label would solve the left margin issue, there is still a problem with `UISwitch` on the right side.

However, you could align your layout with a leading constraint of `textLabel` and a trailing one of `detailTextLabel`.

```
if let leadingAnchor = cell?.textLabel?.leadingAnchor {
    myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
}

if let trailingAnchor = cell?.detailTextLabel?.trailingAnchor {
    mySwitch.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets the leading to `16` on an iPhone SE and `20` on newer devices:

```swift
let leadingConstant = contentView.directionalLayoutMargins.leading
textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: leadingConstant).isActive = true
```

Comment: Why not use `layoutMarginsGuide`? Much simpler. `textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor)`.